# Could Racemic Epinephrine be used to Treat Anaphylaxis?

Tags: pharmacology

To be clear, this question is not a personal health question nor a question seeking health advice, it is only a theoretical question born of a curiosity for the pharmacology and biochemistry of adrenalin/epinephrine... I have never in my life had any kind of allergic reaction and your answer bears no effect on my health or anyone else's health.  The answer will only serve to help a fictional story be as scientifically accurate as possible.

My question is: In theory, is racepinephrine (the active ingredient in Asthmanefrin) compatible as an emergency replacement for epinephrine to combat anaphylaxis?

As a side question, what effect if any, does benzyl alcohol have on epinephrine?

Thank you for your time I certainly appreciate it!